# Compare with sysdate in unix

Tags: unix

I have one file say File.txt that has content as below

```
XYZ_2-3-2013
ABC_12-11-2013
TWP_1-1-2014
UTR_2-2-2014
.
.
.
```

so on.
I suffix part is date part.
Now i need to check the which has 30 days or more older.
For example:as per above file the below has 30 or more days older:

```
XYZ_2-3-2013
ABC_12-11-2013
TWP_1-1-2014
```

As it need to be compare with sysdate.
Could you please help me in the sciprt to find this?

Best Regards,
Quaish

Comment: When you represent dates that way we don't know which parts are the months and which parts are the days!  [Please consider using only YYYY-MM-DD in software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).  That said, are the dates in your question m-d-yyyy or d-m-yyyy?

Comment: @RayToal, try to keep that flexible in your answer ;-)  But of course you are right when you ask OP to clarify on that.

Comment: its in d-m-yyyy. and this is Powercenter generated date format for the backup folders. I have to use this only.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while IFS=_- read x month day year
do
  [ "$(date -d "$year-$month-$day" +%s)" -lt "$(date -d "today - 30 days" +%s)" ] &&
    echo "${x}_$month-$day-$year is more than 30 days ago"
done < inputfile.txt
```

For me it outputs:

```
XYZ_2-3-2013 is more than 30 days ago
ABC_12-11-2013 is more than 30 days ago
TWP_1-1-2014 is more than 30 days ago
```

In case your dates are in format day-month-year, just swap the variable names of the `read`:

```
read x day month year
```

This assumes that you are using a Gnu `date` (or any other which understands the `+%s` formating option).

Comment: Hi Alfe,

Thanks for quick response.

Well,after exceuting the script i am facing the below error:
**date: Not a recognized flag: d
Usage: date [-u] [+"Field Descriptors"]**

Could you please look into this?

Regards,
Quaish

Comment: I fear you have a `date` binary which does not have the feature of printing a _specific_ date :-/  What system are you on?

Comment: Anyway, my solution depends so entirely on that feature of `date` which your `date` is lacking, that you won't be able to use my solution, sorry.